# How to obtain animation_clip from .dae in scenekit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, scenekit, collada

Here is my problem:

I have created 3d animations in Poser Pro and then exported them to .dae file. I've separated animations at animation sets. So each animation set is presented as animation_clip with id in resulted .dae file.

I successfully imported .dae file in Xcode and my animations are working fine! Also, I see my animation set (animation_clip) in preview mode.

[Animation set in preview mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0k4A.png)

But I have no way to obtain certain animation set. It looks like a bug, because:

```
SCNSceneSource *source = [SCNSceneSource sceneSourceWithURL:url options:@{SCNSceneSourceFlattenSceneKey : @(YES),
                                                                          SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyKey : SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyPlayUsingSceneTimeBase,
                                                                          SCNSceneSourceCheckConsistencyKey : @(YES)}];
id identifiers = [source identifiersOfEntriesWithClass:[CAAnimation class]];
// identifiers have neither @"NewSet_2" nor another animations sets that i've created. But all micro animations are there!
```

But I see that animation set in preview mode!

I know I can merge my animations by parsing collada xml but it's felt wrong because Xcode already knows about my animation_clip.